# How to aggregate using distinct values across two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have the following data in an `orders` table:

```
revenue       expenses        location_1      location_2
3             6               London          New York
6             11              Paris           Toronto
1             8               Houston         Sydney
1             4               Chicago         Los Angeles
2             5               New York        London
7             11              New York        Boston
4             6               Toronto         Paris
5             11              Toronto         New York
1             2               Los Angeles     London
0             0               Mexico City     London
```

I would like to create a result set that has 3 columns:

1. a list of the 10 **DISTINCT** city names
2. the sum of revenue for each city
3. the sum of expenses for each city

The desired result is:

```
location         revenue    expenses
London           6          13
New York         17         33
Paris            10         17
Toronto          15         28
Houston          1          8
Sydney           1          8
Chicago          1          4
Los Angeles      2          6
Boston           7          11
Mexico City      0          0
```

Is it possible to aggregate on distinct values across two columns? If yes, how would I do it?

Here is a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1105/1

Comment: Is the sort order in the result significant?

Comment: No, the sort order is not significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorter (and often faster):

```sql
SELECT location, sum(revenue) AS rev, sum(expenses) AS exp
FROM  (
   SELECT location_1 AS location, revenue, expenses FROM orders
   UNION ALL
   SELECT location_2            , revenue, expenses FROM orders
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

May be faster:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT location_1, location_2, revenue AS rev, expenses AS exp
   FROM orders
   )
SELECT location, sum(rev) AS rev, sum(exp) AS exp
FROM  (
   SELECT location_1 AS location, rev, exp FROM cte
   UNION ALL
   SELECT location_2            , rev, exp FROM cte
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1;
```

The (materialized!) CTE adds overhead, which may outweigh the benefit. Depends on many factors like total table size, available indexes, possible bloat, available RAM, storage speed, Postgres version, ...

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BbX3gwBu)

Answer (score 2):

You could UNION ALL two queries and then select from it...

```
select location, sum(rev) as rev, sum(exp) as exp
from (
  select location_1 as location, sum(revenue) as rev, sum(expenses) as exp
  from orders
  group by location_1
  union all
  select location_2 as location, sum(revenue) as rev, sum(expenses) as exp
  from orders
  group by location_2
)z
group by location
order by 1
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. My query was getting twice the size of this one.

Comment: Probably simpler to sum just once in the outer query

Comment: @PhilCoulson Yeah, noticed that after I posted it but didn't change it. Would be curious to know if performance is the same.

Comment: Performance won't be the same. But which is faster depends on many factors. My money is on a single aggregate step. I added a fiddle to compare (note the different query plans!).

Comment: @Isolated I would expect a single aggregation in the outer select to outperform three separate aggregations, but I won't be surprised to be surprised.